# MS Bot composer custom action sample returns null reference exception

Tags: azure, botframework

I've tried to implement the custom action sample (multiply) for the MS bot composer as seen [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/composer/how-to-create-custom-actions). I followed all the steps and copied the code, but when I try to execute the action on the bot, I get a *System.NullReferenceException* with the following stack trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ReplaceDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 offset, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.OnNextActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.EndDialogAsync(Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.SetProperty.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 offset, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.OnNextActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.EndDialogAsync(Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.SendActivity.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 offset, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.ContinueActionsAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ReplaceDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 offset, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.OnNextActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.EndDialogAsync(Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.SetProperty.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 offset, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.OnNextActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.EndDialogAsync(Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.SendActivity.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 offset, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.ContinueActionsAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ReplaceDialog.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 offset, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.OnNextActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.EndDialogAsync(Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.SetProperty.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 offset, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.ReplaceDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.IfCondition.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginActionAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 offset, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.Actions.ActionScope.BeginDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.BeginDialogAsync(String dialogId, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.ContinueActionsAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.ContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.ContinueActionsAsync(DialogContext dc, Object options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive.AdaptiveDialog.ContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.InnerRunAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, String dialogId, DialogContext dialogContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.InternalRunAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, String dialogId, DialogContext dialogContext, DialogStateManagerConfiguration stateConfiguration, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Does somebody know what went wrong here? As far as I know, I followed the tutorial as close as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you didn't forget to add component to appsettings.json

```
"components": [
  {
    "name": "YourCustomActionName"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow these steps to solve this error ***System.NullReferenceException***

***Add the following additional packages to your project file***

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Adaptive" Version="4.9.1"/>

<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Declarative" Version="4.9.1"/>
```

> **Update DefaultActivityHandler**

***Declare two new local variables***

```
protected readonly DialogManager _dialogManager;
protected readonly ResourceExplorer _resourceExplorer;
```

***Update the constructor to includes the following lines***

```
_resourceExplorer = serviceProvider.GetService<ResourceExplorer>();
_dialogManager = new DialogManager(dialog);
_dialogManager.UseResourceExplorer(_resourceExplorer);
_dialogManager.UseLanguageGeneration();
```

***Update the OnTurnAsync handler to use _dialogManager in place of _dialog***

```
await _dialogManager.OnTurnAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken: cancellationToken);
```

**Reference:**

https://microsoft.github.io/botframeworksolutions/skills/handbook/experimental-add-composer/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZJRtyYP0hY

https://github.com/rvinothrajendran/BotTutorialSample